# Linq C# struggling with update code

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, wpf, linq

if anyone can explain to me what is wrong with this I would really appreciate it because its not throwing an exception so I can't see why its not updating the record.

Sorry I should of said I am trying to update an existing record in a database, "CompName" was used as the primary key, this isn't my database design or application or I would of used an int as a id and coded things a lot differently.

```
using (CompanyAndContactDataContext dc = new CompanyAndContactDataContext())
{                
    try {
        Company c = (from datavalue in dc.Companies
            where datavalue.CompanyName == CompName
            select datavalue).First();

        c.CompanyName = txtEditCompanyName.Text;
        c.CompanyEmailAddress = txtEditCompanyEmail.Text;
        c.CompanyTelephoneNumber = txtEditCompanyTelephone.Text;
        c.CompanyFaxNumber = txtEditCompanyFax.Text;
        c.CompanyAddress1 = txtEditAddress1.Text;
        c.CompanyAddress2 = txtEditAddress2.Text;
        c.CompanyAddress3 = txtEditAddress3.Text;
        c.CompanyAddress4 = txtEditAddress4.Text;
        c.PostCode = txtEditPostcode.Text;

        dc.SubmitChanges();
    } catch (Exception exep) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the try catch and you'll see it.

Comment: Oops sorry I forgot to add a message box on the catch... let me look into it again :(

Comment: *Never* have an empty `catch`! At least log the error - in this case it would certainly help you find your error.

Comment: Yeah, never catch an exception, unless you intend to do something with it (Re-throwing doesn't count). Also, try FirstOrDefault() instead of First, unless you're certain there'll be one matching entry

Comment: @Sam If you remove the catch completely, and there is in fact an exception being thrown, Visual Studio will halt at this line, and you can use it to see the details of the exception. Much easier than putting it into a Message Box in your code and trying to work it out that way!

Comment: I feel like a moron for not seeing that before posting, still trying to work out what's going on :D but that will help thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first guess, it's probably the First() call that's throwing the exception. You could make it FirstOrDefault, or try to pass an Id to your method (Make them select a value from a dropdown or auto complete, then get the Id of what they selected). That way you can be sure when this code hits you can update the entry.
If you pass an Id to the method you can even use "Single" or "SingleOrDefault"

Edit:

Say you enter "MyCompany" as CompName, and this doesn't exist in the Database table. If you call First() it'll throw an exception. If you call FirstOrDefault() it'll return "c" as null.

If you call "c.CompanyName" or anything else with a dot, it'll return an exception.

You need to check if c is null before calling any dot methods.

Comment: SingleOrDefault works but I am now getting null reference errors on the values im trying to change.

Comment: @Sam Only use SingleOrDefault if you're giving it a Primary Key or Id. Otherwise FirstOrDefault. You're getting null reference errors, because the default is null. You need to add some code to check if "c" is null, return a message to the user saying what they entered for CompName isn't in the Database